# ngx-bootstrap accordion does not work smoothly in angular2

Tags: angular, accordion, angular2-directives, bootstrap-4

I have used ngx-bootstrap accordion, but it does not work smoothly. I try if click on the accordion group so its toggle smoothly. Please tell us how to do? I am following this reference:- [Angular Bootstrap Accordion](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion)

Component.html :-

```
<accordion>
 <accordion-group #first >
  <div accordion-heading>
   First
   <i class="pull-right float-xs-right glyphicon"
   [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-minus': first?.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !first?.isOpen}">
   </i>
  </div>
  <div>
    Content 1
  </div>
 </accordion-group>

 <accordion-group #second>
   <div accordion-heading >
     Second
    <i class="pull-right float-xs-right glyphicon"
     [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-minus': second?.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !second?.isOpen}"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
      Content 2
    </div>
 </accordion-group>

 <accordion-group #third>
   <div accordion-heading>
    Third
    <i class="pull-right float-xs-right glyphicon"
     [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-minus': third?.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !third?.isOpen}"></i>
   </div>
   <div>
     Content 3
   </div>
 </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

If click on first accordion so open accordion but not smoothly. Please tell open and close accordion with animation like toggle slow.

Comment: To get useful help, you should create a plunkr duplicating the behavior you are describing.

Comment: If you hop onto the ngx-bootstrap's Slack channel, you can see as of June 2017 they have questions about that, essentially confirming that there is no animation for the accordions.

Comment: Check the conversation in this ngx-bootstrap accordion animation issue https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/801 It has been open for 2 years and still no solution. Doesn't look like animations will be added to the ngx-bootstrap accordion.